# Why do we get a coloured spot on TV while dragging a bar magnet near the TV?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism, geomagnetism

Why do we get a coloured spot on old crt TV while dragging a bar magnet near the TV?

Comment: What kind of TV are we talking about? LED, LCD, OLED, Plasma, CRT?

Comment: I am asking this question about crt tv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your old TV uses 3 electron beams to write the color picture information on the inside of the picture tube, the beams will be bent by stray magnetic fields if they are in close proximity to the screen surface. This causes the beams to miss hitting the phosphor spots they were originally aimed at and hit others nearby instead, producing a spot of the "wrong" color.

Most TV's of that vintage had electromagnetic coils built-in to the picture tube assembly which were intended to erase any stray fields in the assembly each time the TV was turned on, so as to prevent weirdly-colored areas like this from appearing on the screen.